# dropdown selecting the value but showing its id need to get the name?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-select

```
<label style="width:49.8em;">Category:
<input type="hidden" name="cat_name" value="cat_name">
<select id="dropdown" name="cat_name">
<?php
echo '<option value="" ><---Select---> </option>';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * from category') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Its selecting the id but need to show the name of the selected id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';`

Or even more simply:

`echo '<option>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';`

If you want the form to submit the name, then use the name. Not the id.

Comment: Thanks jessica .. can u tell me that how to avoid duplicate entry. I have a column of category andno similar name category should be added in it.

Comment: Are they stored in a database? Make the field unique. You'll need to do some error checking to see if the name exists first.

Comment: Yes they are stored in database .
How to make it unique and can u help me in error checking